# Angular get item from Observable<Type<AnotherType>>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have added some server side filtering to angular component.

I'm returning results in page: Observable< Page< Job>>

Displaying and filtering is working perfectly but I need another method to remove items from list and can't work out how to access the items from the component.

Before implementing filtering, i had the jobs in and Array and was removing the job with following method.  While unsaving the job still works, how can I access the individual job from my list  page: Observable< Page< Job>>

```
public unSaveJob(id: string) {
    this.jobService.unSaveJob(id);
    var jobToRemove = this.jobs.find(j => j.Id == id);
    this.savedJobs = this.jobs.filter(j => j !== jobToRemove);
}
```

Page

```
export class Page<T> {
count: number;
next: string;
previous: string;
results: Array<T>;
}
```

If anybody could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Comment: That depends on what `Page<>` is.

Comment: Updated with the various components that are being used

Answer (score 1):

Brain wasn't working when posted this.  So if anybody else has fallen upon this

Simply had to subscribe to the page.results in the constructor

```
this.page.subscribe(data => this.jobs = data.results);
```

and display jobs instead of the page in the component.html